# What does @defer.inlineCallbacks mean when I don't need yield return a value?

Tags: python, scrapy, deferred

At scrapy.core.engine

ExecutionEngine method start

```
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def start(self):
    """Start the execution engine"""
    assert not self.running, "Engine already running"
    self.start_time = time()
    yield self.signals.send_catch_log_deferred(signal=signals.engine_started)
    self.running = True
    self._closewait = defer.Deferred()
    yield self._closewait
```

Why don't use `self.signals.send_catch_log_deferred(signal=signals.engine_started)` directly　but instead of a yield ?

Comment: Not a full answer but you might take a look at this: http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why don't use `self.signals.send_catch_log_deferred(signal=signals.engine_started)` directly　but instead of a yield ?

Because `send_catch_log_deferred` returns a `Deferred` object. If you want to avoid a `yield` there, then you should use `send_catch_log` but the point of using `send_catch_log_deferred` is to allow listeners to return `Deferred` objects.

The signals that use `send_catch_log` are not able to return `Deferred` objects, hence they do not allow to perform asynchronous operations.

Edit: For a good introduction to `inlineCallbacks` see: http://krondo.com/?p=2441

Answer (score 4):

**@defer.inlineCallbacks** expects the decorated function to be a generator function and calling a generator function inside decorated function (even returning one) doesn't make the function, a generator function. An investigation:

```
def gen():
    yield 1

def func(): return gen

import dis

dis.dis(gen)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              3 YIELD_VALUE         
              4 POP_TOP             
              5 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE        

dis.dis(func)
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (gen)
              3 RETURN_VALUE        

import inspect

inspect.isgeneratorfunction(gen)
True

inspect.isgeneratorfunction(func)
False
```

So only way to satisfy **@defer.inlineCallbacks** is either **yield** a deferred from self.signals.send_catch_log_deferred(signal=signals.engine_started) or from somewhere else.